# Left property of css inline

Tags: css

Iam trying to position a control at the centre of a web page depending on the resolution of the page.

The left property I am assigning it in a css class and adding it as follows-
Style class-

```
.PanelStyle
{
   left:100px;
   top:120px;
   border:2px solid #CCC;
   border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}

oPanel.addStyleClass("PanelStyle");//oPanel is my control.
```

This is working perfectly fine.But Instead of hard coding the pixel value for left property I want to assign it dynamically depending on the resolution  .For which I am doing something like below

```
var leftoffset = Math.floor($(window).width()-400)/2+ "px";//400 is my control width
leftoffset = leftoffset.toString(); 
oPanel.style.left=leftoffset ;
```

But this is not reflected in the web page.

I also tried simply adding the left property value without calculation like

```
oPanel.style.cssText="left : 100px";
```

but no use.
Kindly tell me why inline object.style.left/object.style.cssText=cssString is not working here?

Comment: note that `leftoffset.toString()` is redundant as the expression is evaluated as string upon concatenation (`.../2 + "px"`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
$(oPanel).css("left",Math.floor($(window).width()-400)/2+"px");
```

or if `'400'` is your control's `width`, then:

```
$(oPanel).css("left",Math.floor($(window).width()-$(oPanel).width())/2+"px");
```